# Best way to transform dataframe into a date indexed one w/ many columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data fields are "DATE", "ITEM", "CURRVAL", and I have daily data since 2008 (about 4 million records).  I want to transform this so that each "ITEM" is a column with the "DATE" as the index.  This will result in about 1,000 columns (one for each "ITEM") and one row per "DATE".

I'm currently creating a new DF, iterating through the unique ITEMs, and merging a new column to the new DF for each.  This is very slow.  Any tips on how to improve?  Thanks!

```
dfNew = pd.DataFrame()
dfNew["DATE"] = sorted(df["TRADE_DATE"].unique())
dfNew.set_index(["DATE"], inplace=True)
for item in df["ITEM"].unique():
    dfTemp = df[df["ITEM"] == item][["CURRVAL", "TRADE_DATE"]]
    dfTemp.set_index("TRADE_DATE", inplace=True)
    dfNew = dfNew.merge(dfTemp, how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)
    dfNew.rename(columns={"CURRVAL": item}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Look into `df.pivot()`.

Comment: Try `df.set_index(['DATE','ITEM']).unstack(-1)`. Post a sample of your dataframe if you more concrete help.

Comment: @Toukenize perfect- thanks very much!

Comment: @DYZ df.pivot() works even better- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, the solution using df.unstack() and df.pivot().  Pivot does the job more directly:

```
dfNew = df.copy()
dfNew = dfNew.pivot(index="TRADE_DATE", columns="ITEM", values="CURRVAL")

dfNew = df.copy()
dfNew.set_index(["TRADE_DATE", "ITEM"], inplace=True)
dfNew = dfNew.unstack(-1)
```